# How to install a newer version of PHP than what Yum installs?

Tags: php, linux, yum

I have installed PHP by executing the following command:

```
yum install php
```

It installs PHP 5.3.3 in my server... but I want to install PHP 5.4. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Saw it on https://webtatic.com/packages/php54/

To install, first you must add the Webtatic EL yum repository information corresponding to your CentOS/RHEL version to yum:

CentOS/RHEL 7.x:

```
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/epel-release.rpm
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
```

CentOS/RHEL 6.x:

```
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
```

CentOS/RHEL 5.x:

```
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el5/latest.rpm
```

Now you can install php by doing:

```
yum install php54w
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine.But showing  Error: php54w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64.

Comment: Yep, unistall the previous version first. Also, if this answer helped you, mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

`yum` installs approved versions of packages. The approved version depends on a few things, such as your distribution and whether the package itself has been tested and deemed as working. This testing can sometimes lag well behind the development of the packages. Chances are that the version that you have installed is the latest approved version.

Building PHP isn't manually terribly difficult, so that's probably your best option. Uninstall the version you have from `yum` and checkout the [official instructions](http://php.net/git.php) on how to clone and build yourself.

Either that or look around for other packages in `yum` that give you a newer version (see @barbarity's answer).

Answer (score 1):

Reference http://ahmed.amayem.com/replacing-yum-plugin-replace-one-yum-install-package-php-with-another-on-linux-centos-6/

Check available packages

```
rpm -q php
```

Installing the webtatic release RPM(For CentOs 6.x)

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
```

Check for available packages in other repo

```
yum info php55w
```

Trying to update using yum update

```
sudo yum update php
```

Updating using yum remove then yum install

```
yum info php-common
```

Removing php-common

```
sudo yum remove php-common
```

Installing php55w and php55w-common

```
sudo yum install php55w php55w-common
```

Now restart your apache server then check the php version.